# ArcGIS map polygon store in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have to store the created polygon in ArcGIS. Once the polygon is stored in ArcGIS, it returns an ID (Object ID). With the object ID, the administrator can access the polygon in ArcGIS. I found a piece of code in one of our old systems the code is written in version  3xx.

```
function SendFeaturesToParent()
    {
        editingEnabled = false;
        editToolbar.deactivate();
        lyrMeters.clearSelection();

        polygon = currentEVT.graphic.geometry;

        var query = new Query();
        query.geometry = polygon;

        lyrAreas.applyEdits(null, [currentEVT.graphic], null);

        var attributes = [];
        var featureValues = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < selectedfeatures.length; x++) {
            featureValues.push("METER_ID: " + selectedfeatures[x].attributes["METER_ID"] + ", Type: " + selectedfeatures[x].attributes["Type"]);
            attributes.push(selectedfeatures[x].attributes);
        }
        console.log("attributes"+ attributes);
        //Send the array of meter values back to the parent page.
        var objectId = lyrAreas._defnExpr;
      objectId = objectId.split('=');
        window.parent.postMessage(
            {
                event_id: 'my_cors_message',
                data: attributes,
              objectId: objectId[1]
            }, 
            "*" //or "www.parentpage.com"
        ); 
        $('#modelConfirm').modal('hide');
    }
```

I need to implement in latest version of arcGIS API 4.23. What are the applyEdits do?

/**** modified code in 4.23 */

```
var token = '';
const PermitAreaURL = "url_1";
const locatorUrl = "url_2";
const streetmapURL = "url_3";
const streetmapLebelsURL = "url_4";
const MetersURL = "url_5";
const MetersWholeURL = "url_6";

require(["esri/config",
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "esri/layers/TileLayer",
    "esri/layers/VectorTileLayer",
    "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
    "esri/widgets/Search",
    "esri/widgets/Sketch/SketchViewModel",
    "esri/geometry/geometryEngineAsync",
],
    function (esriConfig, Map, MapView, FeatureLayer, TileLayer, VectorTileLayer, GraphicsLayer, Search, SketchViewModel, geometryEngineAsync) {
        esriConfig.apiKey = "AAPK3f43082c24ae493196786c8b424e9f43HJcMvP1NYaqIN4p63qJnCswIPsyHq8TQHlNtMRLWokqJIWYIJjga9wIEzpy49c9v";

        const graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

        const streetmapTMLayer = new TileLayer({
            url: streetmapURL
        });

        const streetmapLTMLayer = new VectorTileLayer({
            url: streetmapLebelsURL
        });

        const lyrwholeMeters = new FeatureLayer({
            url: MetersWholeURL,
            outFields: ["*"],
        });

        const lyrMeters = new FeatureLayer({
            url: MetersURL,
            outFields: ["*"],
        });

        //  const permitAreaUrl = new FeatureLayer({
        //     url: PermitAreaURL,
        //     outFields: ["*"],
        // });

        // console.log(lyrMeters);

        const map = new Map({
            basemap: "arcgis-topographic", // Basemap layer service
            layers: [streetmapTMLayer, streetmapLTMLayer, lyrMeters, lyrwholeMeters, graphicsLayer]

        });

        const view = new MapView({
            map: map,
            center: [-95.9406, 41.26],
            zoom: 16,
            maxZoom: 21,
            minZoom: 13,
            container: "viewDiv" // Div element
        });

        view.when(() => {

            const polygonSymbol = {
                type: "simple-fill", // autocasts as new SimpleFillSymbol()
                color: [207, 34, 171, 0.5],
                outline: {
                    // autocasts as new SimpleLineSymbol()
                    color: [247, 34, 101, 0.9],
                }
            };

            const sketchViewModel = new SketchViewModel({
                view: view,
                layer: graphicsLayer,
                polygonSymbol: polygonSymbol,
            });

            sketchViewModel.create("polygon", { mode: "hybrid" });

            // Once user is done drawing a rectangle on the map
            // use the rectangle to select features on the map and table
            sketchViewModel.on("create", async (event) => {
                if (event.state === "complete") {
                    // this polygon will be used to query features that intersect it
                    const geometries = graphicsLayer.graphics.map(function (graphic) {
                        return graphic.geometry
                    });
                    const queryGeometry = await geometryEngineAsync.union(geometries.toArray());
                    selectFeatures(queryGeometry);
                }
            });
        });

        // This function is called when user completes drawing a rectangle
        // on the map. Use the rectangle to select features in the layer and table
        function selectFeatures(geometry) {


            console.log(geometry.rings);
            // create a query and set its geometry parameter to the
            // rectangle that was drawn on the view
            const query = {
                geometry: geometry,
                outFields: ["*"]
            };

            lyrwholeMeters.queryFeatures(query).then(function (results) {
                var lyr = results.features;
                console.log(lyr);

                // save the polygon
                lyr.applyEdits({
                    addFeatures: [geometry] /*updates*/
                });

                lyr.forEach(element => {
                    console.log(`MeterID-${element.attributes.METER_ID}, OBJECTID-${element.attributes.OBJECTID}, Passport_ID-${element.attributes.Passport_ID}`);
                });
            });
        }

        // search widget
        const searchWidget = new Search({
            view: view,
        });

        view.ui.add(searchWidget, {
            position: "top-left",
            index: 2
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`applyEdits` method is the way you to add/update/delete features in a feature layer. Both version of the library have the method although in version 4 takes an object that contain the edits instead of the separated parameters. In your code, version 3, it is,

```
lyrAreas.applyEdits(null, [currentEVT.graphic], null);
```

first parameter is for new features, second for updates on features and third for features to delete.

While in version 4 it should be,

```
lyrAreas.applyEdits({
    updateFeatures: [currentEVT.graphic] /*updates*/
});
```

the object goes all the informations about the edits, in this case you only have updates.

I am not completely sure about this line,

```
var objectId = lyrAreas._defnExpr;
objectId = objectId.split('=');
```

I am guessing is the definition expression of the feature layer, a sql expression, that is why in the next line it is split, to use later the value. Version 3 library did not expose the property but gives set and get methods.
Version 4 have the property and works in similar way. In this case for latest version it should be,

```
var objectId = lyrAreas.definitionExpression;
objectId = objectId.split('=');
```

So I do not think you will have

[ArcGIS API v3 - FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#applyedits)
[ArcGIS API v4 - FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#applyEdits)

Comment: cabesuon, thanks for the response. I have edited the post by adding my latest code for 4.23. Can you please have a look? Where exactly trhe 'applyEdits' stores the information?

Comment: The edits are made on the layer, whether remote or local. You are not calling the method on any layer, `results.features` is just an array of features is not a `FeatureLayer`. Which is the layer you want to edit?

Comment: 'PermitAreaURL' is a feature layer i want to add a polygon in that layer. Once adding the polygon in the layer, it should return an 'Object ID'. So polygon can be identified by the returned ObjectID. When we pass the ObjectID it should recreate the polygon.

Comment: Then that is the layer where you need to call the method. `applyEdits` returns `Promise<EditsResult>` than when resolved gives the result information of the operation. In the result object there is an entry, `addFeatureResults`, that contains an array of the add results, there you will find the `OBJECTID`. [ArcGIS JS API - FeatureLayer Edits Result](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#EditsResult)

Comment: I have received the objectID. How can we recreate the polygon on map with the objectID?

Comment: You do not need to recreate it, the polygon is already in the layer. You now can query the layer using the id retrieved.

Comment: Cabsuon, the objectid is created and if I search with the objectID, the drawn polygon details are not there but an entry is there. Can you please share a sample code for adding a polygon in a layer as a feature. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73019013/add-polygon-to-teh-featurelayer

Comment: I am referring to https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/editing-applyedits/

Comment: Hi, check the answer I give  you, and let me know

Comment: Thanks! That issue has been resolved. Can you please have a look into the issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73034231/add-more-features-to-the-feature-layer