# Add polygon to teh featureLayer

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I tried go add a polygon to the feature layer. In getting an error in the console,
*Object { name: "feature-layer:missing-parameters", details: undefined, message: "'addFeatures', 'updateFeatures', 'deleteFeatures', 'addAttachments', 'updateAttachments' or 'deleteAttachments' parameter is required" }.* Please correct me. i have added a piece of code which cover creating polygon and applyEdit function on the layer.

```
 require(["esri/config",
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/layers/TileLayer",
        "esri/layers/VectorTileLayer",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/widgets/Search",
        "esri/widgets/Sketch/SketchViewModel",
        "esri/geometry/geometryEngineAsync",
        "esri/Graphic",
    ],
        function (esriConfig, Map, MapView, FeatureLayer, TileLayer, VectorTileLayer, GraphicsLayer, Search, SketchViewModel, geometryEngineAsync, Graphic) {
            esriConfig.apiKey = "AAPK3f43082c24ae493196786c8b424e9f43HJcMvP1NYaqIN4p63qJnCswIPsyHq8TQHlNtMRLWokqJIWYIJjga9wIEzpy49c9v";
    
            const graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
    
            const streetmapTMLayer = new TileLayer({
                url: streetmapURL
            });
    
            const streetmapLTMLayer = new VectorTileLayer({
                url: streetmapLebelsURL
            });
    
            const lyrwholeMeters = new FeatureLayer({
                url: MetersWholeURL,
                outFields: ["*"],
            });
    
            const lyrMeters = new FeatureLayer({
                url: MetersURL,
                outFields: ["*"],
            });
    
            const lyrpermitAreaUrl = new FeatureLayer({
                url: PermitAreaURL,
                outFields: ["*"],
            });
    
            console.log(lyrMeters);
    
            const map = new Map({
                basemap: "arcgis-topographic", // Basemap layer service
                layers: [streetmapTMLayer, streetmapLTMLayer, lyrpermitAreaUrl, lyrMeters, lyrwholeMeters, graphicsLayer]
    
            });
    
            const view = new MapView({
                map: map,
                center: [-95.9406, 41.26],
                zoom: 16,
                maxZoom: 21,
                minZoom: 13,
                container: "viewDiv" // Div element
            });
    
            view.when(() => {
    
                const polygonSymbol = {
                    type: "simple-fill", // autocasts as new SimpleFillSymbol()
                    color: [207, 34, 171, 0.5],
                    outline: {
                        // autocasts as new SimpleLineSymbol()
                        color: [247, 34, 101, 0.9],
                    }
                };
    
                const sketchViewModel = new SketchViewModel({
                    view: view,
                    layer: graphicsLayer,
                    polygonSymbol: polygonSymbol,
                });
    
                sketchViewModel.create("polygon", { mode: "hybrid" });
    
                // Once user is done drawing a rectangle on the map
                // use the rectangle to select features on the map and table
                sketchViewModel.on("create", async (event) => {
                    if (event.state === "complete") {
                        // this polygon will be used to query features that intersect it
                        const geometries = graphicsLayer.graphics.map(function (graphic) {
                            return graphic.geometry
                        });
                        const queryGeometry = await geometryEngineAsync.union(geometries.toArray());
    
                        var graphics;
                        graphics = new Graphic({
                            geometry: {
                                type: "polygon",
                                PERMIT_AREA: queryGeometry,
                            },
                            // attributes:'',
                        });
    
                        const addEdits = {
                            addFeatures: graphics
                        };
    
                        selectFeatures(addEdits);
                    }
                });
            });
    
            // This function is called when user completes drawing a rectangle
            // on the map. Use the rectangle to select features in the layer and table
            function selectFeatures(geometryabc) {
    
                console.log(geometryabc);
                // create a query and set its geometry parameter to the
                // rectangle that was drawn on the view
                lyrpermitAreaUrl.applyEdits({ geometryabc }).then((editsResult) => {
                    console.log(editsResult);
                    console.log(editsResult.addFeatureResults.length);
                    console.log(editsResult.addFeatureResults[0].objectId);
                });
    
                // console.log(geometry);
            }
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error with the line it's failing at?

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) 
Object { name: "feature-layer:missing-parameters", details: undefined, message: "'addFeatures', 'updateFeatures', 'deleteFeatures', 'addAttachments', 'updateAttachments' or 'deleteAttachments' parameter is required" }
​
details: undefined
​
message: "'addFeatures', 'updateFeatures', 'deleteFeatures', 'addAttachments', 'updateAttachments' or 'deleteAttachments' parameter is required"
​
name: "feature-layer:missing-parameters"
​
<prototype>: Object { constructor: l(r, q, k), toJSON: toJSON(), type: "error" }
editingSupport.js:5:522

Comment: I think the problem may be that your 'graphics' variable is being set as a Graphic, however from memory it should be a list of Graphics. 
`var graphics = []; graphics.push(new Graphic(...))`

Comment: Let me know if this isn't it. The error message unfortunately isn't very clear.

Comment: I have changed the variable name to 'graphics_var'. But still not working.

Comment: The variable name is okay, it's just expecting a list, however you're giving it a Geometry. What you need to do is have the original variable name of "graphics" but when you create a new Graphic, you need to add it to a list.

Comment: Okay. I have created an array 'graphics_arr.push(graphics_var);' and pushed created graphic object. Unfortunately the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the function `applyEdits(edits, options?)` takes as mandatory parameter an object of the form,

```
{
    addFeatures: Graphic[]|Collection<Graphic>
    updateFeatures: Graphic[]|Collection<Graphic>
    deleteFeatures: Graphic[]|Collection<Graphic>|Object[]
    addAttachments: AttachmentEdit[]
    updateAttachments: AttachmentEdit[]
    deleteAttachments: String[]
    
}
```

So in your code it should be,

```
function selectFeatures(geometryabc) {
    lyrpermitAreaUrl.applyEdits({ addFeatures: [geometryabc] }).then((editsResult) => {
        console.log(editsResult);
    });
}
```

assuming that `geometryabc` is actually a `Graphic`.

[ArcGIS JS API - FeatureLayer applyEdits](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#applyEdits)